# Interpretation of "which must be widely open to tourist visits"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Particular care should be devoted to preserving and upgrading monuments, shrines and museums as well as archaeological and historic sites which must be widely open to tourist visits.

Interpretations:

1)The care should be devoted to only those sites that are visited a lot. I mean **the sentence puts an emphasis on preserving the sites that are necessarily exposed to tourists, not all existent sites and monuments and the other mentioned**.
Since restrictive clause has been used I jumped to this.

2)The mentioned should be preserved and upgraded and these places must be open to tourists. So **first they should be safeguarded. Then they need to be prepared for visitors and be open to them**. I mean the texts implies an obligation to provide the possibility of being visited. They should not be banned for visitors.
A translation of this text into an Asian language conveys this meaning!

Comment: Either interpretation is possible... can you ask whoever wrote it?

Comment: I am translating this; I don't think I can ask the writer. Could you say which one is better? Source: http://dtxtq4w60xqpw.cloudfront.net/sites/all/files/docpdf/gcetbrochureglobalcodeen.pdf

Comment: The very next sentence should answer the question for you...

Comment: Can you give more context? Your first interpretation is closer to how I would read it. But I would say it means particular care should be paid to sites that must (for some reason) be accessible to tourists, as opposed to sites that could be closed, or where particularly sensitive areas can be closed off from tourists.

Comment: So, you go for the second interpretation, right?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Yes it is the text of a UN document. The text in part seems a bit not fluent to me as well.

Comment: It's a characteristic official policy statement: careful to say what every party wants to hear without expressing anything so clearly that there's no room to waffle out of it.

Comment: @StoneyB Pardon, sir, would you repeat what you said in simpler English?

Comment: It is designed to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

To me, neither of your interpretations seems accurate.  The phrase  “as well as archaeological and historic sites” in this case equals “as well as those archaeological and historic sites”, hence the restrictive clause “which must be widely open to tourist visits” applies only to “archaeological and historic sites”.

The sentence says care to preserving and upgrading should be given for monuments; for shrines; for museums; for archaeological sites that need to be open to tourists; and for historic sites that need to be open to tourists.

Comment: What I don't understand is how a historic site can be _widely_ open to tourists. Is this some kind of jargon I'm not familiar with? I can imagine a door being wide open to tourists, but a site? Widely?

Comment: @Janus, I think *widely* isn't jargon, but either an infelicity or a hypercorrection for *wide open*.  Ie, I take “which must be widely open to tourist visits” as a miswriting of “which must be open to the public”

Answer (score 1):

> Particular care should be devoted to preserving and upgrading monuments, shrines and museums as well as archaeological and historic sites which must be widely open to tourist visits.

I interpret this as case 1) when read continuously as one sentence.

> Particular care should be devoted to preserving and upgrading monuments, shrines and museums as well as archaeological and historic sites, which must be widely open to tourist visits.

If you put a comma after *sites*, reads to me as case 2), since you are separating the preservation from the tourists.